# Select an included values

Tags: oracle, aggregation

I'm using Oracle SQL and i need help with a query. Hope it's not too much easy one. I did't find an answer for it in Google.

I have a table that need to be aggregated by `ID` column and then to select only the records that two values are included in a certain table (and both of them).

Table for example

```
ID | Value
1  |  Y
1  |  N
2  |  N
2  |  N
2  |  Y
3  |  Y
3  |  Y
4  |  Y
5  |  Y
5  |  N
5  |  Y
5  |  N
```

The output table need to include only the IDs that both Y and N are included in Value table. Output:

```
ID
1
2
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution that groups by the ID and uses `HAVING` to return only those with > 1 `DISTINCT` values:

```
with v_data(id, value) as (
  select 1, 'Y' from dual union all
  select 1, 'N' from dual union all
  select 2, 'Y' from dual)
select id 
from v_data
group by id
having count(distinct value) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct a.id
from your_table a inner join your_table b on a.id = b.id and a.value != b.value;
```